# Check if json dict have key with exact value

Tags: python, json, dictionary

```
data = {
  "matches":[
    {"match1": {
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":1.7},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":2.4},
      {"Oddid":3,"Odd":5.1}
    }
  },
    {"match2": {
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":2.3},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":1.9},
      {"Oddid":3,"Odd":1.2}
    }
  },
    {"match3": {
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":2.7},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":4.6},
      {"Oddid":4,"Odd":9.9}
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

How  can I check if every match has "OddId":4.
If it has, i want to print "Odd" value, if it doesen't, i want to print "1.00"
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` is not in the correct format because some of the brackets define a set that includes dictionaries but since dictionaries are unhashable, it gives an error. But after fixing some of the brackets, when can iterate over `data` to print the desired output:

```
data = {
  "matches":{
    "match1": [
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":1.7},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":2.4},
      {"Oddid":3, "Odd":5.1}
    ]
  ,
    "match2": [
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":2.3},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":1.9},
      {"Oddid":3,"Odd":1.2}
    ]
  ,
    "match3": [
      {"Oddid":1, "Odd":2.7},
      {"Oddid":2, "Odd":4.6},
      {"Oddid":4,"Odd":9.9}
   ]
  }
}

for dct in data.values():
    for k, lst in dct.items():
        odd = [d['Odd'] for d in lst if d['Oddid']==4]
        if len(odd) > 0:
            print('{}: {}'.format(k,odd[0]))
        else:
            print('{}: 1.00'.format(k))
```

Output:

```
match1: 1.00
match2: 1.00
match3: 9.9
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use two `for` loop and iterate in `data['matches']` and check the condition.

```py
if key['Oddid'] == 4:
    print("Odd")
else:
    print("1.00")
```

for iterate in a dict that you don't know the keys names this way you can use:

```py
dictname = {"match2": {}, "match1": {}}
for key, value in dictname.items():
```

note: i think your json have one problem, you have one dict without key and value and for this reason i could not write the code.